PCB Impedance mismatch?
I created a very simple PCB, two layers for testing a OXCO.
The overall circuit is as follows:

Now, so far so good from the testing point, I got what I expected: A square wave signal with a maximum voltage around 2 V.

Now , when connecting instead of the oscillator probes to the testing point, a RG316 1 meter BNC cable from the BNC connector of the board to the oscilloscope, I obtain this:

I get 20 V.
What I understood:
Power is reflected when there is an impedance mismatch. I did not calculated the impedance of the PCB board of course. All square waves are just a representation of many sines inside their carrier.
What I tried to calculate an troubleshoot:
Tried to calculate the impedance of the output line to the BNC connector, knowing these parameters:
PCB thickness 1.6 mm, board outline tolerance +-2 mm, trace width 0.254 mm, signal 10 MHz square, 4.10 dielectric constant using Wheeler formula I got 123.65 Ω.
I then tried to create a pi filter for matching these two numbers, but it did not changed anything, still 20 V to "infinite".
Now I am a bit confused, is this related to impedance mismatch or there is other tests I should try out?
*** Edit
Yes it was the oscilloscope set on 10 and not to 1
However this is a test with the same cable and the internal 12 kHz signal from the oscillator itself


10x probe vs the BNC cable not being a 10x probe?

Yes I am an idiot, is always 2 V...

Apart from 1x-10x issue you possibly have with a cable (cable is 1x but the channel is left 10x, quite possibly). RG316 is a 50-Ohm coax, and the BNC connector is 50-Ohm as well. Most OCXOs are able to drive 50-Ohm loads and I assume yours is one of them. So you may want to terminate the cable with 50 Ohms. You may not experience a huge problem (e.g. reflection) with that level of mismatch at frequencies up to 10 MHz, but still worth considering for further tests.

@Ken90 We've all tripped on the 10x probe setting at some point :)

lol i was already on a 4 layer PCB with perfect impedance of 50 ohm :D

@RohatKılıç yes correct, the channel was not on 1 was on 10

Try checking that your scope probe trimmer capacitor is set up correctly for displaying  a decent wave-shape from a signal generator producing a square wave.

@Andyaka done and edited, no distortions

Other than the scope being set to 10x mode and measuring with 1x BNC cable, there seems to be impedance mismatch and that's why the signal edges have ripples because the edges reflect back and forth in the cable.
The problem isn't so much the impedance mismatch of the trace but the source impedance of the OCXO driving the PCB track and 50 ohm cable, and the reflections back from the scope end if the scope end is not terminated with 50 ohms.
The ripples that happen about every about 10 ns means a signal traveling 2 meters in the cable, which means signals definitely reflect back and forth in your 1 meter cable.

how do you think would be possible to mitigate it?

@Ken90 does your scope have an internal 50 ohm input mode?

@tobalt yes  it has

@Ken90 Your PCB design and the oscillator are unknown. We would have to know if you even have bypass caps and what kind of output the OCXO has and if it is even capable of driving such a high load like a 1 meter piece of 50 ohm coax terminated into 50 ohms. Since you have a 50 ohm cable and load, it might be beneficial to also drive the cable (and PCB tracks) with 50 ohm impedance.
